# How was love able to transcend the dimensions of time and space in Interstellar?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

How was love able to transcend the dimensions? And how were *THEY* (people from future) actually able to communicate?

Answer (score 6):

The main theme of Interstellar is that love transcends the dimensions of space and time. Space means distance. We love a person distant from our location, like a friend studying abroad. With respect to time, we love people who have passed away. We go back in time to love their memories. I don't know if love can move forward in time. Maybe feeling love for expected newborn.

*They* built a 5 dimensional space based on the relationship of love between Cooper and Murph. *They* gave each moment a separate room (space) so Cooper can go to whichever moment (time) between him and Murph and try to communicate the means to save humanity.

Answer (score 0):

Love, as used in the movie Interstellar, is an emotion that transcends the third dimension. It is described as existing in the fourth dimension. Because of that. it can escape the time-space continuum.